# any Python built-in API to return minimal element index of a list

Tags: python

Wondering if there are any Python built-in API to return minimal element index of a list? min returns the actual value.

Comment: What do you mean? Minimal element index is zero: `list[0]`.

Comment: @Alex.S Maybe OP wants like `[12, 23, 2, 42, -12, 34]`, and return `-12`. However, if it is. Just do something like this: `sorted(the_list)[0]`

Comment: I think OP wants the index of the minimal element.

Comment: @KevinGuan It's `min(list)` and OP mentions it.

Comment: @Alex.S, sorry for the confusion, I mean minimal value element. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinGuan, yes, I mean the minimal element. You are correct.

Comment: Yes, merlin2011 is correct. :)

Comment: @Alex.S, I want to get the index of minimal element, not the minimal element value itself. :)

Comment: @Alex.S Actually I don't know there is a built-in function called `min()` :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most concise way to do it in Python is to use `mylist.index(min(mylist))`.

Comment: Hi merlin2001, super smart! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Say, the list is `[12, 23, 2, 42, -12, 34]`

```
a = [12, 23, 2, 42, -12, 34]
print a.index(min(a))
```

Output :

```
4
```

Comment: Hi Ahsanul, super smart! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**To get the index of the element with the minimum value**

To get the index of the element with the minimum value in the list, you can just do `some_list.index(min(some_list))`.

```
In [1]: some_list = [12,45345,67,23,7]

In [2]: min(some_list)
Out[2]: 7

In [3]: some_list.index(min(some_list))
Out[3]: 4 # index of the element with minimum value
```

**To get all the indices of minimum value elements if duplicates exist**

Lets say you want all the indices of minimum value elements just in case duplicates exist, then you can do the following:

```
In [1]: some_list = [12,45345,67,23,7,11,7]

In [2]: min_value = min(some_list) 

In [3]: [i for i,v in enumerate(some_list) if v==min_value]
Out[3]: [4, 6] # indices where the minimum element is present
```